# Java comparing custom objects

Tags: java

I've got ArrayList of custom objects. I need to implement sorting by different parametres, i.e. year and price both ascending and descending. What's the best way to do it? I thought about implementing [Comparator](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) and passing sort mode to constructor during  instantiation of comparator. Is that good idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using a different `Comparator` implementation per sort type. Anonymous inner classes, enums and, in Java SE 8(!), lambdas, are good ways to implement `Comparator` and other stateless function-like objects.

You can reverse with [Collections.reverseOrder](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#reverseOrder%28java.util.Comparator%29).

Answer (score 2):

Yes. A custom `Comparator` is a really good way to do it.

As mentioned by @Tom and @Puce, you can [reverse the order](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#reverseOrder%28java.util.Comparator%29) of your `Comparator` on the fly.

Comment: A custom `Comparator` per sort type, but reverse with `Collections.reverseOrder`: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#reverseOrder(java.util.Comparator)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, and for the reverse order you can use:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#reverseOrder%28java.util.Comparator%29

Answer (score 2):

That's one way. But, it really only makes sense if it's a default way. Consider the following Customer class. Typically, you always sort customers by name. But sometimes, you want to sort them by their credit limit.

It makes sense to implement Comparable for convenience. At the very least, you can make the comparators public final components of the class so users have easy access to them, and you can trust they were written by the author of the class (or at least someone with familiar working knowledge of the class.)

```
class Customer implements Comparable<Customer> {

    public final Comparator<Customer> byCreditLimit = new Comparator<Customer>() {
        public int compare(Customer c1, Customer c2) {
            return c1.creditLimit.compareTo(c2.creditLimit);
        }
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            return o == this;
        }
    }

    private String name;
    private BigDecimal creditLimit;

    public Customer(String name, BigDecimal creditLimit) {
        this.name = name;
        this.creditLimit = creditLimit;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if(o instanceof Customer) {
            Customer c = Customer(o);
            return name.equals(c.name);
        }
        return false;
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        return name.hashCode();
    }

    public int compareTo(Customer c) {
        return name.compareTo(c.name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you tell why Comparable is better then Comparator?

Comment: Mostly for convenience. It's a way of saying "Most of the times you sort objects of this type, you should be sorting like this." It's just one less thing to think about. Imagine you're a developer using a class. You want to have the objects sorted for faster lookup times. The developer knows that you should get relatively good distrobution by sorting on the name, while sorting by credit limit would be less efficient (lots may have the same credit, but the equals says a Set will have at most one with a given name.) By using Comparable, the author can supply a default comparison mechanism.

Comment: If a class implements Comparable, it states it has a "natural ordering". Good samples are e.g. the number classes (Integer, Long), which are sorted by the wrapped number. If there is no "natural ordering" or if you want something different than the "natural ordering" -> use a Comparator

Answer (score 0):

The canonical answer is to implement two Comparators - one which sorts in ascending order, and one in descending.