# How to compare and sort objects within an Array

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

Been look around and can not find/understand how comparing objects within an array works. In the code I provided below, how would I be able to compare the objects, within an array based specifically on the cost of the two? Then sorting the Array so the cost is in descending order?

```
public class PC
{
private int VRAM;
public String Processor;
public int RAM;
public int Harddrive;
public double Cost;


 public Desktop(String Proc, int ram, int HD, int Vram)   
{
      Processor = Proc;
      RAM = ram;
      Harddrive = HD;
      VRAM = Vram ;    

}

public double getCost()
{
     Cost = 250 + (5.50*RAM) + (0.10*Harddrive) + (0.30*VRAM);
     return Cost;

}
public String toString()
{        
    return "Desktop\n" + "--------\n" + "CPU: " + Processor + "\nRAM: " + RAM + "GB\n" + "HDD: " + Harddrive + "GB\n" + "VRAM: " + VRAM + "MB" + "\nCost: $" + Cost + "\n";
}
```

}

```
public class Main 
{
public static void main(String[] args)//Main method has been tested throughly, but the output seems to get a bit nasty
{     
    Computer[] ComputerArray = new Computer[5];//when to many are called all out once.
    ComputerArray[0] = (new PC ("Intel Core i7 2600k", 4, 700, 1400));
    ComputerArray[1] = (new PC ("AMD FX-8150", 16, 1950, 1100));
 }
```

}

Comment: Please be sure all variable names begin with a lower case letter. i.e. `ComputerArray` should be `computerArray`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java comparing custom objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5807704/java-comparing-custom-objects)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just create a custome comparator and user Array's sort method.

Comparator :

```
public class CostComparator implements Comparator<Computer> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Computer o1, Computer o2) {
        return o1.getCost().compareTo(o2.getCost());
    }
}
```

and

```
Arrays.sort(computerArray , costComparator);
```

Please change your variable names. Variable names starts with lower case letters.

Comment: okay thanks ill give it a go, and ill be sure to change my instance variables